# DotNetNuke (DNN) and Hyperlink Manager "Track the number of times this link is clicked"

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have clients using the DNN CMS (Evoq Content 7.3.2) system and are questioning a specific area in the "Hyperlink Manager". There are two checkboxes ([View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW1cH.png)):

- Track the number of times this link is clicked
- Log the user, date and time for each click

If checked, where do we go to view these analytics?

I found resources online that mention we have to create an API for it, but are there any out-of-the-box solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more researching, I solved my own problem and I wanted to share this with anyone who was looking for an answer to this.

For versions DNN 7.3.2 and lower, the Telerik RadTextEditor includes the feature as mentioned above. To view the analytics with an out-of-the-box method, simply return back to the link and open the "Hyperlink Manager" then navigate to the new tab called "Tracking".

Alternatively, I found developers can implement a control in a custom module called UrlControl. Refer to this link for more information: [Link tracking information in html editor (DNN 7.1.2)](https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-4208)

In DNN 8+, this feature no longer exists on the front-end UI. I'm not 100% sure if it's still usable or if this information gets migrated when upgrading from 7 to 8, though.